# css not lining up across page

Tags: css

I cannot get the second ul to begin on the same line as the two p tags and the first ul.
It sits down in the bottom right corner, i need it lined up  across the page.
The css is in the html for ease of use while fixing the issue

```
<p style="display:inline;float:left;margin-left:20px;">
    <strong>New Features</strong></p>
<ul style="display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;">
    <li>Distributor area for all ordering, logisitics and planning</li>
    <li>Customer area for usage stats, equipment monitoring and<br /> savings calculators</li>
    <li>Full history for quarterly filings, investor updates and<br /> press releases</li>
</ul>
<p style="display:inline;float:right;margin-right:400px;">
    <strong>This site is best viewed in</strong></p>
<ul style="display:block;float:right;margin-right:15px;">
    <li>FireFox 3.6.13</li>
    <li>Safari 4.0.5 &amp; 5.0.2</li>
    <li>Google Chrome 9.0.597.86 Beta</li>
    <li>Internet Explorer 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if you look on a wide screen - it's exactly what you want. your 2nd `ul` is pushed below the other elements because there is not enough space for it besides them

Comment: well i have a 24inch monitor and at fullscreen they dont line up across

Comment: i think the use of right float is affecting the layout but im not certain, ive tried many variations

Comment: look here - http://jsfiddle.net/zuXyU/embedded/result/

Comment: well it works there but not in chrome or ie